# Почему компилятор не даёт ввести данные в консоль?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

[image: скриншот проблемы]

Вот код, в онлайн-компиляторе он работает, как и все другие. Но в VS code при вводе каких либо значений в консоль пишет, что программа уже запущена.

В чем может быть проблема? Может, есть другие IDE для С, мне нужно очень срочно начать изучение этого языка, но из-за данной проблемы я не могу этого сделать.

Comment: «В чем может быть проблема?» — очевидно в том, что «программа уже запущена».

Comment: Просим вас помимо скриншотов делиться кодом как текст.

[Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%88%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2/12120#12120)

Comment: Учить язык можно и без IDE, если у вас Linux. Для изучения языка вам нужно желание и время.